# Filter string like a slug

Tags: permalinks, slug, formatting, sanitization

I have a WordPress site using pretty permalinks. I want to filter a string to that the it ends up with the exact same formatting as the url slug, does anyone know the filter or function to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`sanitize_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) function:

```
$string = "This is title string";
// return "this-is-title-string"
$slug   = sanitize_title( $string );
```

You can also filter the result of `sanitize_title()` function using [`sanitize_title` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/sanitize_title):

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_title' , 'sanitize_filter_callback', 10, 3 );
function sanitize_filter_callback( $title, $raw_title, $context ) {
    // do something
}
```